# How to update a list of collection in mongo db

Tags: mongodb

I want to update a mongo collection property, which is a list. I want to add a item per update in to the list.

```
{ _id:3,
items:[]
}
```

now i just simply want to add item to the items list by updating the collection many times.

Comment: try with $push or $addToSet operator in mongo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting an example straight from the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#example-push-each)

```
db.students.update(
   { _id: 1 },
   { $push: { scores: 89 } }
)
```

So in your case it would be

```
db.your-collection.update{ {_id:3},
{$push: {items:<your-value>}
}
```